# Behavior of the `quantile` function in R

Tags: r, quantile

When working on a problem I noticed something interesting.  I dont know what exactly happens, but something happens that I did not expect to happen.  It is possible that I made a mistake, but let me start by an example:

```
x <- rnorm( 100 )
y <- x[ x > quantile( x, 0.1 ) ]
z <- x[ x > quantile( x, c( 0.1, 0.2 ) ) ]
a <- x[ x > quantile( x, c( 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ) ) ]
```

We get three different results, but how to interprete these results.  Are these the limits that are used?

UPDATE:
I think i am asking the wrong question.  How can we explain the following:

```
> x <- rnorm( 100 )
> length( x[ x > quantile( x, 0.1 ) ] )
[1] 90
> length( x[ x > quantile( x, 0.2 ) ] )
[1] 80
> length( x[ x > quantile( x, c( 0.1, 0.2 ) ) ] )
[1] 85
```

Comment: My answer is the explanation for your edit as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're confused about `>` and R's recycling behavior. When `quantile` returns more than 1 value (as in the last two examples) it recycles those vectors to be the same length as `x` in order to make the vectorized comparison via `>`.

So, in the last two examples, it repeats the 2 or 3 values from `quantile` over and over again until the resulting vector is the same length as `x` and them compares them element-wise with `>`.

**Edit**

Maybe my explanation wasn't clear enough. In the last line of your edit, `x > quantile( x, c( 0.1, 0.2 ) )` R is comparing the first element of `x` with the 0.1 quantile, the second element of `x` with the 0.2 quantile, the third element of `x` with the 0.1 quantile, the 4th element of `x` with the 0.2 quantile, and so on. Got it? :)

Comment: Yes, the edit of your answer now makes complete sense.  Good to know.  Thanks.